# Full height faux columns

Tags: html, css

I haven't actually coded a website in a few years, so I'm pretty rusty. What I'm trying to do is create a fixed-width and full-height sidebar and a fluid content area. (See visual mockup: http://i54.tinypic.com/2m2b445.png)

I ran across faux columns, and they seem to be doing most of the trick. The only thing the technique isn't doing (and I can't figure out how to make it do) is a full-height sidebar.

Here's the CSS and HTML that I'm using:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
#page-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
* html #page-container {
    height: 100%;
}
#inner-container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#left-col {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
#right-col {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="inner-container">
        <div id="left-col">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li>Dolar Sit Amet</li>
                <li>Consectetur</li>
                <li>Adipiscing</li>
                <li>Elit Integer</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="right-col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the left column full-height? Should I be using a different column technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could position the sidebar absolutely and give the content area the equivalent margin-left:

```
<style>
*, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

/* i would use conditional stylesheets for IE fixes instead */
* html div.column {
height: 100%;
}

div.column {
min-height: 100%;
}
div#content {
margin-left: 250px;
background-color: #FFFF99;
}
div#sidebar {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 250px;
background-color: #99FFFF;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="column">
content
</div>
<div id="sidebar" class="column">
sidebar
</div>
```

**Edit:** One major benefit of this technique is that you can put the content markup above the navigation etc in the page source - a pretty good SEO practice.

Comment: This seems to me like the best option. It cuts down the markup and, as you said, it's good SEO practice. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks, glad I could help! Oh an in all fairness I think Mu got there first!

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to switch your floated left column to an absolutely positioned one and then give it `height: 100%`:

```
#left-col {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XyBzC/

You can also drop the `#inner-container:after` with this approach as that's only there to clear the float left column (which no longer floats).

A version without the `:after`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XyBzC/1/

And [Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854246/joseph) is right in the comments, you can add `padding: 0` to get rid of the scrollbars in the fiddle:

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/XyBzC/2/

Comment: note: you can add `padding:0px` to the body to fix those scroll bars in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Ola: `#right-col` already has `margin-left: 250px;` (which was originally there to keep `#right-col` from wrapping around the floating sidebar). I don't see what difference `min-height` would make but I could be missing something.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks, I merged that in.

Comment: @Joseph: You do not need to specify a unit when the value is zero;  0px, 0em, 0% - they all come to nought!

Comment: @Ola Tuvesson force of habit :P and it looks nicer imo, but you are correct.

Comment: @Joseph: Yeah, but think about the TWO bytes you could be saving! ;)

Comment: @Ola Tuvesson lol XD I made up for it by not adding spaces between padding and 0px XDDD

Comment: @Ola: `#right-col` is not absolutely positioned, it is relatively positioned; `#left-col` is absolutely positioned but it has no margin so your point is moot. And there is no need to worry about `min-height` or `max-height` when you have `height: 100%`; you're free to provide a counter example of course.

Comment: @Mu: Maybe I should have looked at the graphic first - I somehow got the impression the OP wanted the sidebar on the right, not on the left as in the example :P

Comment: @Ola: At least you weren't complaining about absolute positioning :)

Comment: @Mu: Just cleaning up so as not to confuse others!

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is not what's generally considered faux columns. [The seminal article on faux columns is this A List Apart article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). The basic technique is to attach a vertically repeating image that creates the illusion of columns to the parent container of the columns. This ensures that visually the column extends full height.

I stay away from absolutely positioned elements unless they are really necessary (and in this case they are not.)

jsfiddle doesn't seem to allow outside assets (images) so [here's a simple example of faux columns](http://pangram.org/sandbox/faux.html)

Comment: I disagree about avoiding absolute positioning - it has very good, almost perfect, browser support and it can be an extremely useful way of sticking things where you want them. What I would avoid if possible is specifying an absolute unit (such as px) - using absolute with "0" to stick something to the edge of its relative parent is as adaptive and stretchy as any other positioning technique.

Comment: You're right about it not being genuine faux columns though :)

Comment: @Ola Tuvesson There (unfortunately) are still a number of people using IE6 (although that's finally decreasing pretty rapidly). One of the bugs in the IE6 rendering engine is that absolute position and height 100% don't mix well. There are a number of other bugs that absolute positioning trigger in IE6 & IE7 under certain conditions. In general, I think absolute positioning creates more issues than floats. Since absolute positioning removes the element from the flow of the document, I tend to use it only when that is the desired result (source ordering for accessibility reasons, etc.)

Comment: Agreed about IE6, but I bet if you were to test this layout in it the only problem you would have is the lack of min-height support - though this is easily fixed as IE6 erroneously treats "height" as "min-height" (kind of). More issues than floats you say? Hmmm...

Comment: Interesting article. For this, I suppose faux columns aren't quite the way to go. Perhaps if I had a drop-shadow or something, but I don't think it's necessary for this particular design. Thanks for sharing the article, though!

Comment: ALA was the site that first set me on the right path many years ago, and they're still a fountain of insight. I'd recommend anyone who's interested in usability, semantics of markup and graceful degradation to pay them a visit!