# Bootstrap: how to extend my sidebar all the way down to footer?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I extend my left side sidebar all the way down so it connects with the footer?

Here is [my page](http://www.ogmda.com/test/menu.html).

Comment: your `my page` link returns 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current details I would say you need to look up a 'faux columns' solution.  Below are a few links to answer that question

[4 Methods For Creating Equal Height Columns In CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/)

[Responsive full height (equal height) columns using the faux columns css technique](http://codethatworks.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/responsive-full-height-columns-using.html)

[Stackoverflow - Full height faux columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048259/full-height-faux-columns)

As well if you could past more of the html/CSS we could take a look

Comment: Zane, thank you, but i ended up consulting some of my old CSS notes and went with the padding/margin 1000em trick. All is fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a table:

```
<html>
<style>
  html {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  body {
    display: table-row;
  }

  .sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  .sidebar + .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div class="sidebar">a</div>
<div class="content">b</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q7ch74Ly/